# Disable other bar button items when one is being touched: Navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation controller, in its navigation bar i've 2 right bar button items, I want to disable one right bar button when the other is being clicked/tapped. How to achieve this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in you .h file  Declare both Buttons `UIBarButtonItem *btnONe;` and `UIBarButtonItem *btnTwo;` and in your Button Action of btnTwo You can Disable By calling the Method : `btnOne.Enable=NO;` and Viceversa.

Comment: Let me know whether it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `UIBarButtonItems` only have one callback and that's the equivalent of `UIButton`'s `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

If you want to do something when the user presses and releases a button (disable/re-enable other buttons) you might have to get your hands dirty with some custom `UIBarButtonItems` that have `UIButton's` as `customView` and do some careful event handling to know when to enable/disable each.

On a personal note: pressing more than one bar button at the same time is not very common and shouldn't present a problem, whatever implementation you may have.